# Xamarin - AOT: image 'System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a .NET standard library which is used for the data access layer of my Xamarin Android app.

I have added a reference to the library however when attempting to use part of the library that is making web requests using System.Net.Http the app hangs and I get the following output.

```
03-01 16:13:22.914 D/Mono    ( 1874): Image addref 
System.Net.Http[0x7e2f1c7180] -> System.Net.Http.dll[0x7e2f4a2000]: 2
03-01 16:13:22.914 D/Mono    ( 1874): Prepared to set up assembly  
System.Net.Http' (System.Net.Http.dll)
03-01 16:13:22.914 D/Mono    ( 1874): Assembly System.Net.Http[0x7e2f1c7180] 
added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
03-01 16:13:22.917 D/Mono    ( 1874): AOT: image 'System.Net.Http.dll.so' 
not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/TestRecipeApp.TestRecipeApp-
1/lib/arm64/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
03-01 16:13:22.919 D/Mono    ( 1874): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-
cache/arm64/System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library 
"/data/app/TestRecipeApp.TestRecipeApp-1/lib/arm64/libaot-
System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
03-01 16:13:22.920 D/Mono    ( 1874): Config attempting to parse: 
'System.Net.Http.dll.config'.
03-01 16:13:22.920 D/Mono    ( 1874): Config attempting to parse: 
'/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.config'.
03-01 16:13:22.920 D/Mono    ( 1874): Assembly Ref addref 
netstandard[0x7e2f594c00] -> System.Net.Http[0x7e2f1c7180]: 2
03-01 16:13:22.920 D/Mono    ( 1874): Assembly Ref addref 
System.Net.Http[0x7e2f1c7180] -> mscorlib[0x7e46b94000]: 14
Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll [External]
```

Any suggestions would be much appreicxtated as this has taken a whole day of development time and I've still not found a solution.

When db.createUser is called below. The app hangs and does not proceed any further until it eventually crashes. I have tested the createUser function in a console application and it works fine so the problem doesn't seem to be in the class library itself.

```
  class UserPresenter 
   {
     ILoginView loginView;
     DatabaseApi db;
     public UserPresenter(ILoginView view)
    {
        this.loginView = view;
        db = new DatabaseApi();
    }

    public void createUser(string email, string password)
    {

        Android.Util.Log.Error("myError", "In create user");
        bool success = db.createUser(email, password);

        Console.WriteLine("Success: " + success);

    }

  }
```

Cheers.

Comment: System.Net.Http.dll is being loaded: `Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll [External]`, those messages are a part of the probing that Mono does to find an AOT version first, if not found then the `IL`-based assembly is probed to determine if it can be loaded and in your case it is... Your problem is elsewhere, you need to show your code of what is you mean by the "the app hangs".

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the calling code.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm running into the same issue after converting my class library from PCL to .NET Standard 2.0.